# How to run dotnet azure functions with OpenApi3.1?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I just created new .NET Azure Functions project witch contains Http trigger with OpenAPI.

[image]

When I launch project, I see that by default it runs Swagger 2.0.
(In `http://localhost:{myPort}/api/swagger.json` shown my swagger version - `swagger : "2.0"`)

I need some features of Swagger 3.0 (OpenApi 3.0). How and where I can change version?

Comment: Modify your code to use Swagger 3. Swagger support isn't an ASP.NET Core feature. It's added by external packages like Swashbuckle which are configured inside your Program.cs. [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) already supports OpenApi 3

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This project doesn't have Program.cs. Swagger and Swashbuckle configured somewhere else behind scene. Unlike classic asp.net MVC app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution.

Just add this class to your project:

```
namespace AzureFunctions; //My project name

internal class OpenApiConfigurationOptions : DefaultOpenApiConfigurationOptions
{
    public override OpenApiVersionType OpenApiVersion { get; set; } = OpenApiVersionType.V3;
}
```